# MySQL select rows where two column values appear at least once based on a condition

Tags: mysql, sql, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have such a query `SELECT col1, col2 FROM t WHERE col1>1645 AND (col2=5 OR col2=7 OR col2=9)` 
and I'd like to get all rows where for a certain value of col1 all values given by the condition on col2 exist. So e. g. from these records

```
1700, 5
1700, 7
1700, 8
1700, 9
```

3 will be selected while from the following will none, because col2=7 is missing

```
1800, 4
1800, 5
1800, 6
1800, 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, I think this is a bit tricky.  The idea is to find the `col1` values that have all three values for `col2`.  Then, query the table to get the matching `col1`, and `col2` values.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
WHERE t.col2 IN (5, 7, 9) AND
      t.col1 IN (SELECT col1
                 FROM t
                 WHERE col1 > 1645 AND col2 IN (5, 7, 9)
                 GROUP BY col1
                 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col2) = 3
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I miss understand your question but is this what you are asking ? :

```
Select * from T INNER JOIN 
(
    select Col1 , Count(Distinct Col2) as Check_All_Values From  T 
    Where T.Col2 in ( 5,7,9 ) 
    Group by Col1 
    Having Count(Distinct Col2)  = 3
) B
ON T.id = B.id 
WHERE T.Col2 in ( 5,7,9 )
```

Comment: This will not return any results.  How can `col2` equal a different value in the same row?